# How does interpreting negative energy electrons as positrons solve the negative energy problem?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, spinors

How does interpreting negative energy electrons as positive energy positrons solve the negative energy problem? How does change of “interpretation” without fixing the mathematics have such a profound impact on the underlying physics? (After all, don't we still interpret positrons and electrons as excitations of the same underlying spinor field?).

Comment: Hi Dave - we prefer to have one question per post here, so I've removed your second one. Feel free to post it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It basically boils down to the term $e^{-\frac i\hbar E t}$, where the minus can either be included in the energy, making it negative, or into the time. But a negative charge moving backwards in time is *exactly* the same as a positive charge moving forwards in time, and that is much more sensible than negative energy.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look up why charge conjugation reverses time. Great!

Comment: @Dave you can use classical electrodynamics for that, when you swap the sign of all time derivatives and of all charge terms in the Maxwell equations, they remain the same.